# Python 2.7 : Pytz : ImportError: cannot import name timezone

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytz

I installed Pytz library on Suse 13.2 :

```
# python -m easy_install  pytz-2015.2-py2.7.egg
Processing pytz-2015.2-py2.7.egg
Copying pytz-2015.2-py2.7.egg to /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Adding pytz 2015.2 to easy-install.pth file

Installed /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytz-2015.2-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for pytz==2015.2
Finished processing dependencies for pytz==2015.2
```

I checked the python's modules list :

```
# python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Sep 30 2014, 15:34:38) [GCC] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help('modules')
...
argparse            heapq               pytz                wsgiref
...
```

I tried to import the pytz library...

```
>>> import pytz
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pytz.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pytz import timezone
ImportError: cannot import name timezone
```

Someone have an idea why it's impossible to import this library ?

Comment: I am not sure if it has something to do with your problem. But in the [docs](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/#localized-times-and-date-arithmetic) the example shows how to make the imports. Maybe the order matters?

Comment: Just curious, why do you install pytz this way? Why not just `easy_install pytz` or `pip install pytz`?

Comment: to be sure to install the library for python 2.7 and not 3.x ;-)

Comment: I tried those imports but with the same error  :from datetime import datetime, timedelta
>>> from pytz import timezone
>>> import pytz

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [The name shadowing trap](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-name-shadowing-trap).

Rename your script from `pytz.py` to `test_pytz.py` to avoid the conflict with the `pytz` package.

Answer (score 0):

Didnt you install Django on your computer?
i think you first have to install Django ,and then for importing timze zone in Django 1.4 and upper versions u can write:

```
from django.utils import timezone
```

and for Django 1.3 you can use:

```
from datetime import datetime
```

Comment: `pytz` is an independent Python package. `django` may use `pytz` but it has nothing to do with the quesiton.

Comment: but his answer helped me, so +1.